# moving an object to the same position of another object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move an object to the exact same position of another object so I tried this piece of code:

```
public void Click(){
        x=GameObject.Find("Corner7");
        y=GameObject.Find("Corner8");
        x.transform.position=y.transform.position;
        x.transform.rotation=y.transform.rotation;
    }
```

but nothing is moving! I tried to print the position of the two objects and it results with the same position although both of them are in two different places! can anybody please help? thanks in return.
here's the hierarchy, x object is corner7 and y is corner8.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I35fB.png)

Comment: Post a screenshot of x and y game object and the hierarchy. That would would help answering your question.

Comment: @Programmer x object is corner8 and y is corner7 here's the screenshot http://imgur.com/TvPUPQe

Comment: talking to yourself mate?

Comment: @Vucko for the weird coincidence we have the same username lol no i'm not taking to myself

Comment: yeah, haha.. Take a look if your problem has something to do with coordinate systems they belong to -> as far as I recall, they can be in global and local systems and their coordinates differ. Google this and double check it.

Comment: click edit and put in ***all*** of the ***actual code*** you used.  use the copy and paste feature.

Comment: in your photo, note that the two objects ***appear to have children***.  please ***expand*** those arrows and take another photo.  it's very likely the sub-objects are offset in some way, that's all it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like parent/child position problems. Maybe one of your objects is a child and you only moved the child of that gameobject instead of the parent. So the location of the parent and child are different. Try to get the child position of that y gameobject if it has a child.

Comment: the two objects are children of the same parent, could that be possibly the problem?

Comment: It looks like. You have Object inside object then inside object and inside object. Show what is inside Corner8 and Corner7. Also which one is is named x and which one is named y?

Comment: I see that you updated your code. I want to see the hierarchy of both Corner8 and Corner7.

Comment: I updated the screenshots, their children are just planes made with 3dmax

Comment: When you want to make object a child, you should make sure that the child objects transforms are zeroed in the scene. Then you can move the parent and this problem wont be there. Zero all the child in  Corner8 and Corner7 and your code should work. If you don't want to do that for some reason, you can use code to match yellow and red, blue and white.... instead of matching  Corner8 and Corner7.

Comment: I'm sorry but what do you mean by "zero all the child in corner8 and corner7"? if I set the transform in inspector their position will change.

Comment: On the Editor it has Transform with x,y,z. Zero 3 of them for each object that is a child of Corner8 and Corner7.

Comment: Since you have multiple objects under this I don't think this is the solution you want. Doing this with code is much more easier. What objects do you want to match the position of each other? For example, Red7 moves to yellow9....... White9 moves to Blue1? Tell me how you want it and I will fix it.

Comment: I want to rotate the whole upper plane clock wise as if you are scrambling the rubik's cube, so I started testing it on two cubies (Corner7 and Corner8), I'm interested in seeing the rotation like sliding it with your hand to the left and seeing the upper plane moving, that's why i don't want to match children.

Comment: Your question is about position not rotation and my answer points to you that the problem is because of the child thing. You can move each child individually and still be able to rotate Corner7 and Corner8. I don't know your programming level but you need to start small before making a rubik's cube game. You need to find another way to implement this.

Comment: I don't think this answered your question but you really need another way to do this. I wish there is another I could help but your scene not simple and your game looks complicated...... Good luck with your game.